# After a while from running perfectly, the app crash

Tags: android, arduino, android-bluetooth

So I was working on an arduino project that send char via bluetooth to my app. The app receive the data. If the char is "1" it plays a voice clip called "the"
else if its "2" plays voice clip called "its_me".

The app run just fine for a while like for 2 or 3 min and then it crashes. This is the logcat:

```
en02-05 21:12:56.060 7715-7715/bluetooth.arduino.ndroid.bluetooth3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: bluetooth.arduino.ndroid.bluetooth3, PID: 7715
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1551)
        at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:1503)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:947)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:930)
        at bluetooth.arduino.ndroid.bluetooth3.MainActivity.malek(MainActivity.java:223)
        at bluetooth.arduino.ndroid.bluetooth3.MainActivity$2.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:74)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

and this is the java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaPlayer TheSound;
    private static final String TAG = "bluetooth2";
    TextView txtArduino;
    Handler h;
    final int RECIEVE_MESSAGE = 1;        // Status  for Handler
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    // SPP UUID service
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // MAC-address of Bluetooth module (you must edit this line)
    private static String address = "98:D3:31:F9:4C:52";

    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer TheSound) {
            releaseMediaPlayer();
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtArduino = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtArduino);      // for display the received data from the Arduino



        h = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // if receive massage
                        byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                        String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 // create string from bytes array
                        sb.append(strIncom);                                                // append string
                        int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
                        if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                            // if end-of-line,
                            String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // extract string
                            sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "the connection has set up ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                           malek(sbprint);
                        }
                        //Log.d(TAG, "...String:"+ sb.toString() +  "Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
                        break;
                }
            }

            ;
        };


        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
        checkBTState();


    }


    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10) {
            try {
                final Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[]{UUID.class});
                return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection", e);
            }
        }
        return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

        // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        // Two things are needed to make a connection:
        //   A MAC address, which we got above.
        //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
        //     UUID for SPP.

        try {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
        }

        // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
        // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
        Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
        try {
            btSocket.connect();
            Log.d(TAG, "....Connection ok...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
            }
        }

        // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
        Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    private void checkBTState() {
        // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
        // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
        if (btAdapter == null) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
        } else {
            if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
            } else {
                //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void errorExit(String title, String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
                    h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();     // Send to message queue Handler
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


    }
    // determent the voice clip and update TextView
    public void malek (String sbprint){
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        TheSound  = MediaPlayer.create(this,mmalek(sbprint));
        TheSound.start();
        // I created a global var for when TheSound is finished , releas the resources
        TheSound.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
    }
    // determent which voice clip to play
    public int mmalek (String theX ){
        txtArduino.setText(theX);    // update TextView
        if(theX.equals("1")){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             return R.raw.the;}

        if(theX.equals("2")){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " it's me", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return R.raw.its_me;
            }

    return 0;}
    /**
     * Clean up the media player by releasing its resources.
     */
    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        // If the media player is not null, then it may be currently playing a sound.
        if (TheSound != null) {
            // Regardless of the current state of the media player, release its resources
            // because we no longer need it.
           TheSound.release();

            // Set the media player back to null. For our code, we've decided that
            // setting the media player to null is an easy way to tell that the media player
            // is not configured to play an audio file at the moment.
            TheSound = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException` looks like a missing Android resource id at particular line `MainActivity.java:223`...it may not be related to Bluetooth.

Comment: I have look it up , no resource id id is missing  , but I will try to change the way that I'm getting the RES ID in the line 223 and will see .  **thank****you**